# When will the reader option appear in Samsung's Internet-browser?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung, stock-browser

Samsung's browser called "Internet" offers for some sites a separate reader. But not for all sites. What is the criterion to offer the little green box? It looks quite random to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is based on content of site, if any site comes under categories: Article, documentation,  blog,  news or same kind comes under browser reader feature,  hope you got you answer.

Comment: Who does categorize the site?